# Modifying RNN CuDNN example code to use CUDNN_DATA_INT8

Tags: recurrent-neural-network, cudnn

The RNN example (RNN_example.cu) that is in cudnn_samples_v7 is set up to use `CUDNN_DATA_FLOAT`. I'd like to modify it to use `CUDNN_DATA_INT8`. When I globally made this change, compiled and run, I get the following runtime errors:

```
$ ./RNN_int8 20 2 512 64 0
cuDNN Error: CUDNN_STATUS_NOT_SUPPORTED RNN_example_int8.cu 285
cuDNN Error: CUDNN_STATUS_NOT_SUPPORTED RNN_example_int8.cu 302
cuDNN Error: CUDNN_STATUS_BAD_PARAM RNN_example_int8.cu 309
cuDNN Error: CUDNN_STATUS_BAD_PARAM RNN_example_int8.cu 310
cuDNN Error: CUDNN_STATUS_NOT_SUPPORTED RNN_example_int8.cu 326
cuDNN Error: CUDNN_STATUS_NOT_SUPPORTED RNN_example_int8.cu 328
CUDA Error: out of memory RNN_example_int8.cu 330
cuDNN Error: CUDNN_STATUS_BAD_PARAM RNN_example_int8.cu 373
cuDNN Error: CUDNN_STATUS_BAD_PARAM RNN_example_int8.cu 402
cuDNN Error: CUDNN_STATUS_BAD_PARAM RNN_example_int8.cu 373
cuDNN Error: CUDNN_STATUS_BAD_PARAM RNN_example_int8.cu 402
cuDNN Error: CUDNN_STATUS_BAD_PARAM RNN_example_int8.cu 373
cuDNN Error: CUDNN_STATUS_BAD_PARAM RNN_example_int8.cu 402
cuDNN Error: CUDNN_STATUS_BAD_PARAM RNN_example_int8.cu 373
cuDNN Error: CUDNN_STATUS_BAD_PARAM RNN_example_int8.cu 402
cuDNN Error: CUDNN_STATUS_BAD_PARAM RNN_example_int8.cu 482
cuDNN Error: CUDNN_STATUS_BAD_PARAM RNN_example_int8.cu 516
cuDNN Error: CUDNN_STATUS_BAD_PARAM RNN_example_int8.cu 541
```

For example, the error at line 309 is running this code:

```
cudnnErrCheck(cudnnSetFilterNdDescriptor(wDesc, CUDNN_DATA_INT8, CUDNN_TENSOR_NCHW, 3, dimW));
```

I suspect the format type (`CUDNN_TENSOR_HCHW`) isn't correct for the data type - is that the correct hypothesis? If so, what format is needed here?

Comment: I suggest providing a [mcve].  See item 1 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Among other requirements,   int8 requires proper underlying support in the hardware.  You may also just want to search the [developer guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/sdk/cudnn-developer-guide/index.html) for every instance of int8.

Comment: I'm concluding based on the CUDNN_STATUS_NOT_SUPPORTED that CUDNN_DATA_INT8 is not supported for these RNN model API calls eve though the Nvidia docs do not stipulate any such restriction. Oh if only CuDNN was open source so I could just look at the code and see for sure.

Answer (score 1):

CuDNN currently doesn't support `INT8 RNN`, we suggest you use FP16 input output to achieve better performance than `float`. If you use Volta be sure to turn on `CUDNN_TENSOR_OP_MATH` to get hardware acceleration.

All supported config combinations of cuDNN RNN can be found here
https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/sdk/cudnn-developer-guide/index.html#features-of-rnn-functions
Let us know if you have any other issues!

Comment: @Y_X: A while back I tried modifying that example (RNN_example.cu) to use CUDNN_DATA_HALF, but run into lots of issues. Later on I found out about CUDNN_TENSOR_OP_MATH and the CUDNN_TENSOR_OP_MATH_ALLOW_CONVERSION  and tried those with the original example code, but didn't see any speedup.